# Google Drive Sdk- Audio & Video Streaming in iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Hi Google Drive Staff,

I have tried to **stream video files from Google Drive**(Without Downloading). But I gets alerts that Sign In. I have went thoroughly  with Dr. Edit sample App but i did not found any solution. I tried with **downloadUrl , embedLink, webContentLink, alternateLink**. All gives message to sign In. When i tried with **exportsLinks i get a Null Message**. What is the problem Here. If U have any suggestion Please Let me Know...

I have tried with Google Drive for iOS in iPod, there we can stream Video without Downloading.
Please suggest me to resolve this issue

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could solve it just by appending the access_token to the download url

```
audiofile.strPath=[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@&access_token=%@",downloadUrl,accessToken];
```

pass the strPath to your avplayer object to play music.

I did not try the video part. but i think a similar approach should work.

you can fetch the access token from the GTMOAuth2Authentication object

Note that you might need to refresh it if its expires.

Hope this helps you.

Regards
Nitesh

Comment: Thanks for answering this question bro. I ll get back to u soon

Comment: @Nitesh! Thank you so much! Finally found a correct answer after months!

Comment: @Nitesh I followed this code for accessing the "Access Token"     NSString *googleDrivefileURl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&access_token=%@",file.downloadUrl,GTMOAuthObject.accessToken]; But AccessToken is getting NULL. what can I do? Actually i imported GTMOAuth2Authentication.h Header file. i did alloc init for that class Object

Comment: you receive an GTMOAuth2Authentication object when you authenticate . In the - (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
                 error:(NSError *)error
You need to store authResult and use the accessToken property.
After the expiry you need to refresh the accessToken again. You will know it has expired if the access Token property is nill. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. @Nitesh.I checked its working good. But your last point "You will know it has expired if the access Token property is nill". I can't understand. can you elaborate it.

Comment: And even How to get the Access Token using Refresh Token [After expired]. can you give me any ideas to implement this. @Nitesh

Comment: Oh i have not worked on it. rather than refreshing the token again all the time. just save it in a NSUserDefaults . use this token in the NSUserDefaults and it will still work. this hack worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Nitesh, I think You answered my question, which was long awaited and i stopped working on it also. But Really The developers from google drive also not helped but you answered in effective and simplest manner. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends what you mean by "stream". Last time I looked, the download links all had a content disposition: attachment header, which instructs the browser to download rather than render the content.

If you have your own client fetching the url, you can choose to ignore that header and do what you like with the content as it is fetched. imho, it would be nice if the client could add a parameter to the url to indicate to the Google servers that it wants the content to be rendered v. downloaded, but hey ho.

Comment: I had tried all. i have checked that url , which i get for Downloading file, it is not authorized it ask for authentication. My download url already contains permission id and file id.

Comment: I ultimate goal is to Play audio and video from Google Drive (Without Downloading). if u have any idea in making a url publicly accessed. i will be thankful to u..

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Please share if you did :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize all requests to `downloadLink`s with an Authorization header. Read more about the authorization and learn how to retrieve your users an access token on https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth

Comment: The link i am getting from file.downloadUrl ask to authorize in browser. But with same link i m downloading the file. It means that file is authorized. if it works for downloading than why i doesn't work for Streaming...

Comment: thanks for ur support. but one final question is it possible to get public url, which can be used by browser, player..plz reply

Comment: how to make authorize request to downloadLink with an Authorization header in Objective C. there is no example in documents. plz improve ur answer ...

Comment: If you are using our client lib, a sample is available on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get under Objective-C tag. If you implemented your own, add an `Authorization` header in the following format `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>`.

Comment: How to add Authorization: Bearer <access_token> in objective .. it is not given in ur code

Comment: Please if u could improve ur answer by adding access token in Objective c... it would help me resolve my issue....thanks

Comment: Still problem is not resolved. if u could improve answer by some code for how to add Authorization.

Comment: plz elaborate ur answer with code... as a beginner in iOS it is tough for me. You are experience developer for u it seems easy..Plz help me how can i do it...Thanks for ur response