# Stream video file in GoogleDrive in iOS using MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4

I am currently working on an app which requires that i stream videos on my google drive to my iphone.
I could list all the files and folders .
I can even display all the files like ppt,docx in a UIWebView
But when i pass the url of the video to the MPMoviePlayerViewController
it throws up this error.

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
kind = 1;
new = 2;
old = 0;
}
```

Its a mp4 video.

The video works fine on the Google Drive iOS app.
Has anyone faces this issues?

Thanks for your help in advance

Nitesh

Comment: Yes i did
you might want to check out my answer at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893183/google-drive-sdk-audio-video-streaming-in-ios-application/22711269#22711269