# Stream Google Drive Music via V3 API

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am able to stream music file of google drive using downloadUrl method of V2 API, but is there is any alternate method in V3 API to fetch downloadUrl?

```
GTLQueryDrive *query =
    [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
    query.q = @"mimeType='audio/mpeg' or mimeType='audio/x-m4a'";
    query.fields = @"files(id,name,parents,webContentLink)";
    [self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {

        if (error == nil) {

            GTLDriveFileList *fileList = (GTLDriveFileList *)object;

             NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?alt=media", NSURLfileList.files[0].webContentLink];

    AVPlayer(initWithUrl:songUrl).play() // abstract method for stream, ignore syntax

        } else {
            //error
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: Please consult the documentation and come back if you have any problems.

Comment: @DalmTo Consulted documentation, able to fetch webcontentLink and all, but not able to stream. Any idea how to generate streaming link?

Comment: Can you show some code so that we can help you.

Comment: @DalmTo Question Updated with code, please check and suggest alternate method for streaming in V3 API

Comment: I cant sorry I am not an IOS programmer that's why its best when asking a question to always tag with the language and add your code from the start.   Its tagged now hang in there someone with the power of IOS should respond.

Comment: Have you checked out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893183/google-drive-sdk-audio-video-streaming-in-ios-application) by @Nitesh? It suggests to pass the access_token to the `AVPlayer` object to play music

Comment: @adjuremods The above answer works for V2 API. In V3 API downloadUrl method is removed. I tried with webContentLink as an replacement for downloadUrl but it doesn't work